# Android ringtone picker refresh the activity, why?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

in my app i have some layout to edit a task and select a RingTone and save it into the database.
When i update the task, i one also to update the ringtone name. I use for that the ringtone picker, start a new Intent and get the selected ringtone uri inside the onActivityResult() method.

The problem ist, every time when i click to pick the new RingTone the page reload and i lose all the populated data in my formular, that come from the database.

How can i solve this problem. Is there a way to open the ringtone picker without reload the complete activity after selecting the ringtone?

Here is how i open picker:

```
    protected void openRingtoneDialog() {

    final Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, getString(R.string.ringtone_choose));

    if (mAlarmTonUri != null) {
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, mAlarmTonUri);
    } 
    else {
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, RINGTONE_RESULT);
}
```

and here, how i get the selected ringtone.

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {

    String ringTonTitle = "";

    // Get the result from RingtoneActivity
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RINGTONE_RESULT) {
        mAlarmTonUri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);          
        if (mAlarmTonUri != null) {
            mAlarmTonValue = mAlarmTonUri.toString();
            ringTonTitle = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, mAlarmTonUri).getTitle(this);              
        }
        else {
            ringTonTitle = "unknow";
        }

        mAlarmTonTextView.setText(ringTonTitle);
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: have you check android:configChanges ? is "orientation|screenSize" or other factor kill your activity?

Comment: I try to put orientation|screenSize in my Manifest, but the same problem persists. The activity refresh everytime i choose the Ringtone, and i loose all the data i puted in the other fields. Please help me!

Comment: try to location in debug mode, set a break point on the life cycle method such as onDestroy etc, of activity. check out if what happen to the activity?

Comment: if you can make sure the activity is destroy when rington activity is appear, then check out the docs for configchanges:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this in my app. I had overridden `onResume` to reload my view in case changes were made while my app wasn't on top. Coming back from the ringtone picker was setting off my `onResume`. For me, it was safe to move everything from `onResume` to `onStart`. There it would run when my app came to the foreground or first started but not when the ringtone picker was dismissed.